# get function of stringstream doesn't remove characters

Tags: c++, inputstream

In the documentation, it says that `stringstream::get()` will extract a character from a stringstream. However, for me, this function is behaving like `stringstream::peek()` is described:

```
stringstream test("/A/B/C/D/E");
test.get();
cout << test.str();
```

As far as I understand, this should print `A/B/C/D/E`, but instead, `/A/B/C/D/E` is printed.

Comment: The string inside the stream will always be the same, the read-position in the stream will on the other hand change as you read from the stream. Note that it say that `get` it extracts from the *stream* and not the string.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `getline(test, str)` with a temporary string.